# Why would subversion timeout when I try to commit changes to a directory?

Tags: svn, file, ssl, filesystems

When attempting to commit file in the jsunit directory in my working-copy, I waited a really long time and got an error like:

```
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn_repo/OSB_Project/trunk/OSB/test/web/jsunit'
svn: timed out waiting for server
```

Why would the server hang at this point?

Running SuSE 10.3 in a VirtualBox where I keep my Subversion server

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the options in subversion anyway.

Comment: Oh and by the way I also recently moved the repository (via svn dump and svn load) to a file based system.  Before it was on an SSL server running apache 2 and webdev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I solved this one, myself!

I grepped through the files in the subversion (.svn) directory for the phrase "http" only to discover that in the file "entries" the directory itself was still pointing to the non-existent SSL subversion server.  I made the file point to the repo on the file system and now it works fine!

Problem solved!